# web app shows errors when deploying in tomcat but works fine in eclipse

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have developed a web-app which has database connections. It works fine when executing through eclipse but when deployed in tomcat server manually it shows several errors which are mostly related to servlets. some of the errors are database-connection errors(sql exceptions) and some shows unable to execute/load xyz.class.....what could be the problem here..??

Errors ...

`java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Log_Ser threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dee.Log_Ser.doGet(Log_Ser.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Comment: post any of your errors ?

Comment: @san krish this the error.....java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: have you the `ojdbc` jar in your buildpath?

Comment: @sankrish....SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Log_Ser threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.dee.Log_Ser.doGet(Log_Ser.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

Comment: its throwing `null` check whether you get the data correctly in the servlet. try debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess as you mentioned

> it works in eclipse not in the server

**You have missed exporting your jar files with the application**

1. So you need to export them like below,

[image]

Check the jar files , you need to export,

[image]

And export your war file . so it gets exported with all external jars in the build path